# Python and QT returns "none" when parsing PDML files

Tags: python, parsing, pyqt4

I am trying to parse PDML files using the WiresharkXML python module. I wanted to start by counting the number of packets in a PDML file.

It works fine when I created a small command line program, when I try to produce the same results in a QT GUI, it keeps returning the answer as "none", where it should be an integer.

It's seems as though there is a problem with it calling the def packet_cb(packet): section of code maybe?

Anyway here is the my code

```
import WiresharkXML
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


num_packets = 0

    def showDialog(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
        filename2 = str (filename)

        pdml = open(filename2)
        num_packets = WiresharkXML.parse_fh(pdml, packet_cb)
        self.lineEdit.setText('The PDML File Contains '+ str(num_packets)+' Packets')

def packet_cb(packet):
    "Called once for each packet."
    global num_packets
    num_packets += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PDMLPacketCounter = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_PDMLPacketCounter()
    ui.setupUi(PDMLPacketCounter)
    PDMLPacketCounter.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To answer this question requires going through a lot of code. This makes it hard to give good answers without spending disproportionate amounts of time on the question; most people will rather move on to another question. If you distil the question down to the smallest possible sample that reproduces the problem the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well. The edited question does not have to do the same thing as the whole of the code, it only needs to reproduce the one aspect that you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `show_dialog`, you're assigning a local variable `num_packets` which shadows the global variable by the same name. I suspect the local variable is `None`, and the global variable has the integer you're expecting. If you the return value from `WireSharkXML.parse_fh` is not useful, you should simply call it without an assignment:

```
def showDialog(self):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
    filename2 = str (filename)

    pdml = open(filename2)
    WiresharkXML.parse_fh(pdml, packet_cb)   # NOTE: No assignment on this line any more!
    self.lineEdit.setText('The PDML File Contains '+ str(num_packets)+' Packets')
```

Comment: I am only a beginner with Python so thank you for the excellent explanation, this works